# Word for a shelf intended to be worked off of like a desk

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

I'm trying to figure out a more descriptive word than "shelf" for a structure that is mounted to a wall at around waist height intended to be used as a desk. This is creative nonfiction so I know exactly what it looks like.

Ways it is like a desk, not a shelf:

- Computers are put on it along with things that are intended to be worked on.
- People sit at it working in chairs
- It is not used to store or display things

Ways it is like a shelf, not a desk:

- It is At waist height
- It has no drawers
- It is mounted to the wall and not freestanding.

The intended sentence goes something like: "They sat at the shelf/desk/____" and/or "He worked on the shelf/desk/____". With the latter, "worked on the shelf" usually refers to preforming maintenance.

Comment: Maybe the very broad *work station* (which applies to much more).

Comment: Another common term for this entity is _work surface_.

Answer (score 4):

A *counter* or *countertop* fits the description. As a home designer, that's what I would call such a surface. It implies a working surface and waist height (a work surface designed for use while standing).

> The flat working surface on top of waist-level kitchen cabinet. (MW)

Answer (score 3):

The common term would be a `wall-mounted` table.